# How to continue the loop through each cell of Next Row?

Tags: excel, vba

As seen below, I have 3 sheets, viz: Sheet "Shops-Fruits Data", Sheet ("Months"), and Sheet ("Output").

I am trying to copy the data from Sheet "Shops-Fruits Data" based on months from Sheet ("Months") to ("Output") structure. I have written a code. However, with this code I can only iterate through first row. I don't understand, how do I continue to the next row till the last row. Second, I also can't copy the Shops and fruits name to the Sheet ("Output").

I have manually copied the desired result in Sheet Output table as seen below, there you can see what I want to achieve. It would be great if anyone can lead me! Thank you.

**Sheets("Shops-Fruits Data")**

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  | 2021 | 2021 | 2021 | 2021 | 2021 | 2021 | 2021 | 2021 | 2021 | 2021 | 2021 | 2021 |
| 2 | Shop | Fruits | Quantity | JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY | JUN | JUL | AUG | SEP | OCT | NOV | DEC |
| 3 | Walmart | Apple | Quantity | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 | 60 | 70 | 80 | 90 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 4 | Walmart | Orange | Quantity | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| 5 | D-Mart | Apple | Quantity | 36 | 38 | 40 | 42 | 44 | 46 | 48 | 50 | 52 | 54 | 56 | 58 |

**Sheets ("Months")**

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | JAN |
| 2 | FEB |
| 3 | MAR |
| 4 | APR |
| 5 | MAY |
| 6 | JUN |
| 7 | JUL |
| 8 | AUG |
| 9 | SEP |
| 10 | OCT |
| 11 | NOV |
| 12 | DEC |

**Sheets ("Output")**

| Shop | Fruits | Year | Month | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Walmart | Apple | 2021 | JAN | 10 |
| Walmart | Apple | 2021 | FEB | 20 |
| Walmart | Apple | 2021 | MAR | 30 |
| Walmart | Apple | 2021 | APR | 40 |
| Walmart | Apple | 2021 | MAY | 50 |
| Walmart | Apple | 2021 | JUN | 60 |
| Walmart | Apple | 2021 | JUL | 70 |
| Walmart | Apple | 2021 | AUG | 80 |
| Walmart | Apple | 2021 | SEP | 90 |
| Walmart | Apple | 2021 | OCT | 10 |
| Walmart | Apple | 2021 | NOV | 11 |
| Walmart | Apple | 2021 | DEC | 12 |
| Walmart | Orange | 2021 | JAN | 12 |
| Walmart | Orange | 2021 | FEB | 13 |
| Walmart | Orange | 2021 | MAR | 14 |
| Walmart | Orange | 2021 | APR | 15 |
| Walmart | Orange | 2021 | MAY | 16 |
| Walmart | Orange | 2021 | JUN | 17 |
| Walmart | Orange | 2021 | JUL | 18 |
| Walmart | Orange | 2021 | AUG | 19 |
| Walmart | Orange | 2021 | SEP | 20 |
| Walmart | Orange | 2021 | OCT | 21 |
| Walmart | Orange | 2021 | NOV | 22 |
| Walmart | Orange | 2021 | DEC | 23 |
| D-Mart | Apple | 2021 | JAN | 36 |
| D-Mart | Apple | 2021 | FEB | 38 |
| D-Mart | Apple | 2021 | MAR | 40 |
| D-Mart | Apple | 2021 | APR | 42 |
| D-Mart | Apple | 2021 | MAY | 44 |
| D-Mart | Apple | 2021 | JUN | 46 |
| D-Mart | Apple | 2021 | JUL | 48 |
| D-Mart | Apple | 2021 | AUG | 50 |
| D-Mart | Apple | 2021 | SEP | 52 |
| D-Mart | Apple | 2021 | OCT | 54 |
| D-Mart | Apple | 2021 | NOV | 56 |
| D-Mart | Apple | 2021 | DEC | 58 |

**The code I am trying:**

```
Sub test()

Dim c As Range, d As Range, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
Dim Mon As String


Set ws1 = Sheets("Shops-Fruits Data")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Months")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Output")

LastRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
i = 2
For Each c In ws2.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    Mon = c.Value

    With ws1.Range("D2:O2")
        Set d = .Find(Mon, , LookIn:=xlValues)
    With ws3.Range("D:D")
          'Copy Months
          .Cells(i, 1) = c.Value
          'Copy Year
          .Cells(i, 0) = d.Offset(-1, 0).Value
          'Copy Quantity
          .Cells(i, 2) = d.Offset(1, 0).Value
          'Copy Fruit Name till December.
          .Cells(2, -1) = d.Offset(1, -1).Value 'But it fails!
          'Copy Shop Name till December.
          .Cells(2, -2) = d.Offset(1, -2).Value 'But it fails!
            i = i + 1
           'How do I continue to next row now?
    End With
    End With
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear what the purpose of the Months" sheet is.  Your output look like a straight "depivot" of "Shops-Fruits Data"

Comment: @Tim Williams The purpose of Months" Sheet is just to find the respective months data from the Shops-Fruits Data sheet

Comment: The month is there on your data sheet though?

Comment: @Tim Williams Nah, I created it just to search Months in Sheet "Shops-Fruits Data" . But, I think you have a valid point, I looked it at twice and it looks like a "Unpivot" of Sheet "Shops-Fruits Data" . Then ,  I recorded a macro and I got what I want ! Only the year I will past manually! Thanks for the tip though! Best Regards! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic depivot:

```vb
Sub Depivot()
    
    Dim arr, arrOut, r As Long, c As Long, rOut As Long
    
    arr = Worksheets("Data").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Value   'input data to array
    ReDim arrOut(1 To UBound(arr, 1) * UBound(arr, 2), 1 To 5) 'resize output array (approx. size)
    'loop input array
    For r = 3 To UBound(arr, 1)
        For c = 4 To UBound(arr, 2)
            rOut = rOut + 1
            arrOut(rOut, 1) = arr(r, 1)
            arrOut(rOut, 2) = arr(r, 2)
            arrOut(rOut, 3) = arr(1, c)
            arrOut(rOut, 4) = arr(2, c)
            arrOut(rOut, 5) = arr(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r
    'place the output on a sheet
    Worksheets("Depivot").Range("A1").Resize(rOut, 5).Value = arrOut

End Sub
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks a lot! Have a nice time! :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the point placed by Tim Williams, here is the code for unpivoting the data.

```
Sub test()
    
    
        Sheets("Shops-Fruits Data").Range("Table10").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Query", Formula:= _
            "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=""Table10""]}[Content]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""Shop"", type text}, {""Fruits"", type text}, {""Quantity"", type text}, {""JAN"", Int64.Type}, {""FEB"", Int64.Type}, {""MAR"", Int64.Type}, {""APR"", Int64.Type}, {""MAY"", Int64.Type}, {""JUN"", Int64.Type}, {""JUL"", Int64.Type}, " & _
            "{""AUG"", Int64.Type}, {""SEP"", Int64.Type}, {""OCT"", Int64.Type}, {""NOV"", Int64.Type}, {""DEC"", Int64.Type}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Unpivoted Other Columns"" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#""Changed Type"", {""Shop"", ""Fruits"", ""Quantity""}, ""Attribute"", ""Value"")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Unpivoted Other Columns"""
    
        With Sheets("Output").ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
            "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Query"";Extended Properties=""""" _
            , Destination:=Sheets("Output").Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
            .CommandType = xlCmdSql
            .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Query]")
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .PreserveColumnInfo = True
            .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_10"
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
        Range("F2").Select
    End Sub
```